# Get selected item from listview and change the color of selected item

Tags: vb.net, listview

User will select one of the person in the listview to assign as a Team Leader, and the selected item will change to specific color.

Below is my coding so far, but I got an error:

> InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.

[image: listview table]

```
 Private Sub lvLBSkillsetSEL_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lvLBSkillsetSEL.DoubleClick
        If lvLBSkillsetSEL.SelectedItems.Count < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a Team Leader.", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim _strCLID As ListViewItem
        Dim _strCLName As ListViewItem
        Dim _reply As Integer
        Dim bSkip As Boolean = False


        'Get CLID from selected listview
        With lvLBSkillsetSEL.SelectedItems
            If .Count > 0 Then
                _strCLID = .Item(0)
                _strCLName = .Item(1)

                _reply = _
                            MsgBox("You've choosen " & _strCLName.Text & " as their Team Leader." & vbLf & _
                                   "" & vbLf & vbLf & _
                                   String.Format("Labour: {0} | {1}", _strCLID.Text, _strCLName.Text), _
                                   MsgBoxStyle.YesNo + MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, _
                                   Application.ProductName)

                If _reply = MsgBoxResult.No Then
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    bSkip = True

                End If
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: what line is triggering the error?

Comment: You declare two variables with "str" prefixes and then declare them as type `ListViewItem`. I hate Hungarian Notation at the best of times but when it is deliberately wrong then it's way worse.  I suspect that your issue is here: `_strCLName = .Item(1)`. Your code requires that at least two items are selected but you only check that there is at least one. Do you really want to select two items or do you actually want to select one item and then get two subitems from it, i.e. two columns from one row?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'd be interested to know your reasoning behind your anti-Hungarian-Notationism